# gmail new email contents and transfer to google spreadsheet automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, gmail-api

I found this website which is useful and the way I want. But sure it's not for free. I was wondering if there is any google-app script that I can use and do the same thing automatically.

[https://zapier.com/]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr6Ne.png]

Comment: Post the code you have written, then you can get help with it. Writing code is hard. Some people make a living with that skill, so don't expect to get code for free.

Comment: I would suggest you to kindly read the follows : [ask] , [Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) . And as @teylyn has said, you need to show some of your work. This place works like that. Best of luck :)

Comment: @teylyn I would gladly pay if you can please help me out with that.

Comment: Well, there's your solution. Pay for zapier. Or post the code you've written, so we can help you with that.